# Show category with images in homepage Magento2

Tags: magento2

Show category with images in homepage Magento2

http://ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-frontend-how-to-call-category-collection-on-home-page

This article working fine but I need to show category image.How to fetch category images also

I am using $category->getImageUrl();

but its not working

Comment: What is the out put when code ' echo $category->getImageUrl(); '

Comment: please see this link [magento stackexchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/166487/magento-2-how-to-get-category-image/#answer-301436)

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get this to show on the homepage by combining the tutorial and R T's answer. Because i didn't have a _objectManager (and the page was kicking an error when i tried R T's code) working on that page, I included the category model in the block file (Collection.php)

```
protected $_categoryHelper;
protected $categoryFlatConfig;
protected $topMenu;
protected $categoryView;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Flat\State $categoryFlatState,
    \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu $topMenu,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $categoryView
) {

    $this->_categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;
    $this->categoryFlatConfig = $categoryFlatState;
    $this->topMenu = $topMenu;
    $this->categoryView = $categoryView;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
```

I then added a method to call in the phtml at the bottom of the block file.

```
    public function getCategoryView() {
    return $this->categoryView;
}
```

In the phtml (storecategories.phtml) I changed up the code to work like this.

```
<?php
$categories = $this->getStoreCategories(true,false,true);
$categoryHelper = $this->getCategoryHelper();
?>
<ul>
<?php
    foreach($categories as $category):
        if (!$category->getIsActive()) {
            continue;
        }
?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $categoryHelper->getCategoryUrl($category) ?>">
<?php
    $catId = $category->getId();
    $categoryAgain = $this->getCategoryView()->load($catId);
    $_outputhelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
    $_imgHtml   = '';
    if ($_imgUrl = $categoryAgain->getImageUrl()) {
        $_imgHtml = '<img src="' . $_imgUrl . '" />';
        $_imgHtml = $_outputhelper->categoryAttribute($categoryAgain, $_imgHtml, 'image');
        /* @escapeNotVerified */ 
        echo $_imgHtml;
    }
?>
    <?php echo $category->getName() ?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

And then i added the new call into the di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Ibnab\CategoriesSide\Block\CategorisCollection">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="deleteorderAction" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="context" xsi:type="string">\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context</item>
            <item name="helper" xsi:type="string">\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category</item>
            <item name="flatstate" xsi:type="string">\Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Flat\State</item>
            <item name="menu" xsi:type="string">\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu</item>
            <item name="categoryview" xsi:type="string">\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to do this as below in template:

```
    $category = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($item->getId());
    $_outputhelper    = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');

    $_imgHtml   = '';
    if ($_imgUrl = $category->getImageUrl()) {

       $_imgHtml = '<img src="' . $_imgUrl . '" />';
    $_imgHtml = $_outputhelper->categoryAttribute($category, $_imgHtml, 'image');
    /* @escapeNotVerified */ 
    echo $_imgHtml;
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: This widget might help : https://github.com/Programmingatkstark/Magento-2-Category-with-image-widget